# Getting Exception when using nearbySelection in VRPTW in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I seen a blog for scaling VRPTW for more than 1000 location using nearby selection.
I tried implementing that, here is the xml I wrote :

```
<unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector id="entitySelector1">
                    <entityClass>vehiclerouting.domain.Customer</entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector variableName="previousStandstill">
                    <nearbySelection>
                        <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector1"/>
                        <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>vehiclerouting.domain.solver.nearby.CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
                        `<nearbySelectionDistributionType>PARABOLIC_DISTRIBUTION</nearbySelectionDistributionType>
                    </nearbySelection>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector id="entitySelector2">
                    <entityClass>vehiclerouting.domain.Customer</entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
               <secondaryEntitySelector>
                    <entityClass>vehiclerouting.domain.Customer</entityClass>
                    <nearbySelection>
                        <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector2"/>
                        <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>vehiclerouting.domain.solver.nearby.CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
                        <nearbySelectionDistributionType>PARABOLIC_DISTRIBUTION</nearbySelectionDistributionType>
                    </nearbySelection>
                </secondaryEntitySelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
```

Here is the **Exception** I get (while running with 154 customer):

```
2017/09/12 12:15:00.538 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (153), time spent (6850), score (-70002hard/-57992000soft), selected move count (156), picked move (161581 {null -> 161582}).
2017/09/12 12:15:00.547 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [INFO] org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (6859), best score (-70002hard/-57992000soft), score calculation speed (1842/sec), step total (154).
2017/09/12 12:15:00.599 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was INACTIVE is now DISPOSED
2017/09/12 12:15:00.603 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was INACTIVE is now FIRING_ALL_RULES
2017/09/12 12:15:00.607 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was FIRING_ALL_RULES is now HALTING
2017/09/12 12:15:00.607 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was HALTING is now INACTIVE
2017/09/12 12:15:00.641 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] [DEBUG] mobi.fareye.module.rabbitmq.AutoRoutingListener - Exception : 
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: null
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.nearby.NearbyDistanceMatrix.addAllDestinations(NearbyDistanceMatrix.java:35) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.nearby.NearEntityNearbyEntitySelector.phaseStarted(NearEntityNearbyEntitySelector.java:96) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:37) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:49) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:37) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:49) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.FilteringMoveSelector.phaseStarted(FilteringMoveSelector.java:51) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:37) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:49) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.phaseStarted(LocalSearchDecider.java:95) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.phaseStarted(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:115) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:64) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87) ~[optaplanner-core-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
```

I think, I might be doing some wrong in xml config. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on that line and figure out why destinationSize is negative. Is it the childSize that is negative or the overallSizeMaximum?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet - It is happening because of overallSizeMaximum is negative :
`if (destinationSize > overallSizeMaximum) {
                        destinationSize = overallSizeMaximum;
                    }`

Comment: Can you [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) with a reproducer?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet -Okay I will. For now is there any temporary fix, so that I can use nearby selection .

Comment: One more thing It only fails if I use :  
`<nearbySelectionDistributionType>PARABOLIC_DISTRIBUTION</nearbySelectionDistributionType>`

Comment: can you link that jira here?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible because there's [a sizeMaximum of at least 1 check](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/heuristic/selector/common/nearby/ParabolicDistributionNearbyRandom.java#L34), at east in 7.7.0.Final and later (and a number of versions sooner too).

Comment: I have also experienced this issue and accordingly raised bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1225